# Find missing HTML tag

Tags: html, tags

Is there a tool which I can use to see missing tag in HTML?

For e.g. if I wrote `<div>` but forgot to end it with `</div>` so is there a tool for this? I have a very large HTML file and I suspect because of missing tag I am having problems in displaying so need some tool that can identify it.

Comment: "Internet Explorer 10" is best for your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any Tools To Find Missing HTML Tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307178/any-tools-to-find-missing-html-tags)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Any tool which gives you basic text editing tools can tell you this very easily.Some useful tools are:
1. Visual Studio
2. Notepad++ 
3. MS word(yes this also shows)
4. Front Page(very old player in this field)
Lots of many more.
Above of all, open your page in chrome or Mozilla then press F12, see the code and fix it.

Comment: This is a list of software and not a solution for the problem. For example, what do you do to fix the closing tag after you've opened Firefox inspection tool?

Answer (score 4):

Try to validate page on [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/) (validate via file uplod)it will show all errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Auto-Format` feature (Ctrl+K+D) of Microsoft Visual Studio - it reformats your code so that you can easily see whether there are missing tags. I love this feature, it often comes in handy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://validator.w3.org/ or notepad++ is the best option to check div's.